# Match array items value and assign new value to associative array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have an associative array with multiple array items in PHP, in which some array items have specific values like ccdbh-743748 and some have not.
I needed to check by running a loop on this array that if any array item has this value  ccdbh-743748, then add a new key to that array item like this 'profile_type' => 'primary'.
and if there is no matching value on another array item then add a new key to that array item like this. 'profile_type' => 'secondary'

Here is the array structure.

```
0 => array(
    array(
        'id' => 'ccdbh-743748',
        'name' => 'test',
        'email' => 'testemail@test.com'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 'uisvuiacsiodciosd',
        'name' => 'test',
        'email' => 'testemail@test.com'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 'sdcisodjcosjdocij',
        'name' => 'test',
        'email' => 'testemail@test.com'
    )
),
1 => array(
    array(
        'id' => 'sdcisodjcosjdocij',
        'name' => 'test',
        'email' => 'testemail@test.com'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 'ccdbh-743748',
        'name' => 'test',
        'email' => 'testemail@test.com'
    )
)

I want the result should be like this

0 => array(
    array(
        'id' => 'ccdbh-743748',
        'name' => 'test',
        'email' => 'testemail@test.com'
        'profile_type' => 'primary'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 'uisvuiacsiodciosd',
        'name' => 'test',
        'email' => 'testemail@test.com'
        'profile_type' => 'secondary'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 'sdcisodjcosjdocij',
        'name' => 'test',
        'email' => 'testemail@test.com'
        'profile_type' => 'secondary'
    )
),
1 => array(
    array(
        'id' => 'sdcisodjcosjdocij',
        'name' => 'test',
        'email' => 'testemail@test.com'
        'profile_type' => 'secondary'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 'ccdbh-743748',
        'name' => 'test',
        'email' => 'testemail@test.com',
        'profile_type' => 'primary'
    )
)
```

Any progressive workaround for this query, either with pre-built in PHP functions or some custom solution for this.

Comment: seems fairly straight forward. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Kinglish I am new to code, and i was trying to achieve the results like by using array_column and then preg_match the values but did not find how to set secondary value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably more elegant ways to go about this, but you can just use a couple foreach loops...

```
foreach( $source as $sub ){
    $newsub=[];
    foreach ($sub as $item) {
        $p = ($item['id']==='ccdbh-743748') ? 'primary' : 'secondary';
        $item['profile_type']=$p;
        $newsub[]=$item;
    }
    $newsource[]=$newsub;
}

print_r($newsource);
```

Example: https://tehplayground.com/s5QTv7QfBde6V8pi